# how to log sql queries executed by sequlize ORM?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am setting up a project with express js, sequelize ORM and mysql database. is there a way i can also log or set up something , so that I can log/dump sql queries constructed/executed by sequlize ORM?

index.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize({

  host: 'localhost'
  dialect: 'mysql'
  ..
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, {  
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: console.log
})
```

Comment: Another way , you can make logging: true as well, it will work same.
`logging: true`